# Where can I find more cartoon videos like BBC's Muzzy for a young child to learn Mandarin?

Tags: learning, resources

I'm not talking about instructional videos and bi-lingual videos. Just Mandarin cartoon videos which a young child, with the ability to naturally absorb a new language, can use to learn Mandarin.

Comment: [River Dragon King](http://www.mandarinadvantage.com/) (note: paywall) has plenty positive references from my friends. They have some teasers on Youtube for your consideration.

Comment: Thx bytebuster. I think that one is bilingual rather than just Chinese.

Comment: How young is the child? I am not familiar with BBC's Wuzzy (never heard of it), but for a 4 year old, 黑猫警长 is quite suitable in my opinion.

Comment: She's 4. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan I'm closing this as NC for now. Please refer to our [FAQ] point *"Can I ask for resources?"*, it will you give you enough info. Please note that closed questions are not *just gone*. You can still improve it according to the guidelines. After you do it, just flag it for moderator attention and let us know, we'll reopen it. My best suggestion is: make it as narrow and scope you can. If your question asks for a small range of answers only, you're set. The problem is with broad and open-ended questions. :) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [Muzzy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzzy_in_Gondoland)? I've never seen that show, but I do have a 5 year old and I regularly let him watch videos from [CCTV's official video site](http://shaoer.cntv.cn/) which has full length episodes of things like [Thomas and Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_&_Friends) in Chinese Mandarin.

My recommendation is to show your child 小小智慧树 [link to video page here](http://shaoer.cntv.cn/cctvchildren/xiaoxiaozhihuishu/videopage/index.shtml). This is a popular children's TV show in China and is educational, directed at younger children and has quite simple dialogue. Each episode also has a simple song and poem which my son found easy to sing along with.

On the video page you will notice their are videos marked 《小小智慧树》 followed by a date e.g. 20120928. These are the full length episodes.

I find showing my son these shows are much more valuable than having him stare blankly at cartoons as they encourage participation via dance, song and activities.